# Why does the --save-dev option adds a dependency as "version number or later" rather than "this exact version number"

Tags: node.js, npm

If I do `npm install "grunt-contrib-uglify" --save-dev`, the following line will be added to my dev-dependencies:

```
grunt-contrib-uglify: "^0.4.0",
```

I thought it was a best practice for a build script to refer to exact version of required tools, and manually upgrade tools when needed, in order to avoid regressions at an inappropriate timing in the build process.

So I was surprised that the added line is not

```
grunt-contrib-uglify: "~0.4.0",
```

Am I missing something here ? Should I always change the ^ to a ~ after using the `--save-dev` option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ~ doesn't mean exact version either, both ~ and ^ are part of [semver](http://semver.org/) and indicate different levels of non-breaking changes i.e. it will bring down bug fixes and refactors but not breaking changes.

How much you trust this is up to you really.  Do you trust the package owner to not introduce breaking changes when making bug fixes?  Do you trust your testing to catch any problems?  If not, then you would want to not have any symbol before the version to get the exact version.  You can also [shrinkwrap](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/) your dependencies.

**EDIT:** For more about the meaning of ~, ^, and other symbols in package.json, see https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver. For this specific case:

> ~1.2 := >=1.2.0-0 <1.3.0-0 "Any version starting with 1.2"
>
> ^1.2 := >=1.2.0-0 <2.0.0-0 "Any version compatible with 1.2"